# If Statements in print to loop new <li>

Tags: php

I am looping information from database as `$id` , `$akt` and `$nmn`. I want to make some if-statements in this print if its possible.

I have a counter before my loop `$counter = 0;` and adding `$counter++;`

I want to print `td` with the dropdown once. But i want to print the `li` as long there is any in database.  I think the right way is to it with a counter. But i need some help. Any suggestion?

```
   print("<td class='center'><div class='dropdown'> 
     <button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' 
      type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'> Activities
      <span class='caret'></span></button>
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li><a href='#'>$id , $akt , $nmn </a></li>
      </ul>
     </div> 
    </td>\n");
    print("</tr>\n");
```

I have many `td` in this `tr`.

```
This is what i wanna do.


if ($counter < 1){  
print("<td>>$produktionsgrupp</td>\n");
print("<td>$namn</td>\n");
print("<td>$kvikt</td>\n");

print "<td class='center'> <div class='dropdown'> <button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' 
      type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'> $nmn
      <span class='caret'></span></button>
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
}

print "<li> <a href='#'> $nmn </a> </li>";
if ($counter < 1){  
print "</ul> </div> </td>\n"; 
print("</tr>\n");
}
```

Comment: if($couter > 0){ //dont show li}else{//show li}

Comment: i've updated what i want to do

Comment: why cant i do if statments inside my print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First print things that you print only once:

```
print "<td> <div> <ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
```

Then loop the data you retrieved from your db:

```
foreach ($data_from_db as $data) {
    print "<li> <a href='#'> $data </a> </li>";
}
```

Then close the elements you've opened before:

```
print "</ul> </div> </td>";
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, your question was not quite clear. Feel free to comment tho, hope it helps!

Comment: Nice approach. i think im close now. Im updated the post

Comment: Try it, and comment again if something didn't work for you :D

Comment: Can you look at my latest one? i took ur approach , but changed the foreach part.

Comment: It does look better, but is there a reason for using a counter like that? it makes it less readable imho. It's like you're saying "if it's not the first loop don't print this", instead of "print this once, then loop my data, then print this once again". It's okay anyway, but remember that readability is as important as functionality. Is it working now?

Comment: not really yet. but im closer. i gave u thumb up. gj